# How to hide 'Add To Cart' for variable products, but keep product variations visible

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

When I try to hide the 'Add to cart' button, the variations disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the way to remove add to cart button and quantities in Single product pages for variable products only, keeping the attributes select fields:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_add_to_cart_button_variable_product', 1, 0 );
function hide_add_to_cart_button_variable_product() {

    // Removing add to cart button and quantities only
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks. Works as described!

Comment: Thank for you reply. I actually got the relevant code from https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ which is why you'll notice a different add_action line of code. Adding the wholesale conditional only occurred to me after I could not figure out why it wasn't working exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I did this, since I have variable products on separate RETAIL pages that I want to keep the 'Add to cart' button

```
 function remove_add_to_cart(){
    if ( has_term( 'wholesale', 'product_tag' ) ) {

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation','woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
}
} 

add_action('woocommerce_single_variation','remove_add_to_cart');
```